# Magento 1.9.1 Rounding Issues

Tags: php, magento, rounding, magento-1.9.1, rounding-error

i have been spending the last 2 weeks trying to solve rounding issues on my magento installation, i have already searched on google, i have already read all the posts here on stackoverflow but nothing seems to help.

[This is where rounding error occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azhdN.png)

As you can see in the image we have:

- total: 308,72€
- total with tax (iva 22%): 376,63€
- total expected: 308,72*1,22 = 376.6384, with rounding UP: 376,64€
- so tax is 1 cent less, which is a big problem
- the problem seems to appear in a random way, i couldn't find any patterns or condition which cause this issue.

Here some info about the environment:

- Magento version 1.9.1 (still need to update to SUPEE-8788)
- CoolBaby Theme (latest version)
- Plugin used:
- 1)PHOENIX Magento-CashOnDelivery
- 2)Extendware: Full Page Cache
- 3)Extendware: Minify css/js
- Mysql Version: 5.6.33
- Php Version: 5.5

Here are some solutions and config combination i have already tryed:

- Disable all plugins
- Change the roundPrice function to 4 decimal instead of 2
- Creating a new magento 1.9.1 installation using the same db
- Changing calculation mode, none of the 3 options resolve the problem, actually the best method seems to be "Total"
- Changing "Price include taxes" in calculation mode config
- Changing Cash on Delivery fee include tax
- Changing Shipping Cost include tax

In my catalogue i have a lot of products with very small price but the problem appear also when all prices have only 2 decimal.

A strange fact is this: in the example i have COD which is 10€ with vat included, if i remove COD and i add a product with the same price (10€ with vat), the total with taxes is correctly rounded to 376,64€

Maybe i'm missing something, i don't know, i'm not so expert with magento, but i really don't know what to check now, any advices or idea will be appreciated

Comment: Magento 1.9.1 does not support PHP 5.6 (1.9.3 does), so immediately you have a compatibility problem that could be (while probably isn't) causing problems for you

Comment: Sorry, on the production server the actual php version is 5.5.38

Comment: It's likely a problem with your expectations of the tax calculation, rather than with the software. For one thing, you'll end up with different totals depending on whether tax is computed per item and then totalled (as seems to be happening here) or whether it's computed directly on the total. For another, you can't expect mathematically that (1) computing tax from a gross total, (2) rounding it to the nearest cent (3) subtracting off that tax to get a net total, and then (4) recomputing the tax and rounding will end up recovering exactly the original value; you could easily be off by a cent.

Comment: Some reading material: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/sales-tax-rounded-then-totaled-or-totaled-then-rounded

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks for the support, I understand the point, but to our law, the bill shown in the example is a fraud and there may be serious legal consequences, so this is actually a big problem because i can't ask my customer to check all invoices to see if the vat is wrong. In the example i reported, all price are configured without vat (also for shipping cost and COD) so in this case the calculation (which is based on total) should be pretty linear. 
Does this occur also in newest magento version?

Comment: @GianlucaCiambellotti: There's a fundamental mathematical problem here that no amount of software is going to solve. For example: suppose a 22% tax rate, with tax calculations always rounded up, and suppose that your total (including tax) is 30 EURO exactly. What should the base price be reported as? A base price of 26.22 gives a total with tax of 31.99. A base price of 26.23 gives a total with tax of 32.01. There is *no* possible base price that "works", and no amount of software or configuration is going to change that.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are right, but in both case if i set the base price without tax to 26,22 or to 26,23, the final vat calculated should be correct

(26,22 * 1,22 = 31.9884 => 31,99 vat = 5,77)

(26,23 * 1,22 = 32,00 => 32,00 vat = 5,77)

Both result are correct.
By the way, how people deal with this problem? they just don't care?